# Filter dates stored as varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 on the EC2 instance. I have a database having 4 fields of all varchar(50).

```
 SELECT
 *
FROM
 xyz
WHERE
 DataDate ='20140609'
```

This query gives no result.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 xyz
WHERE
 DataDate = (Select MAX(DataDate) from xyz)
```

This query runs perfectly.

```
Select MAX(DataDate) from xyz
```

This query results in 20140609.

I cannot understand why this this happening. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: What is the type of `DataDate` column? 
If it's varchar type, maybe you have trailing tabs after `20140609` in this row?

Comment: can you show sample data?

Comment: Why would you store a date in a varchar(50) column? I'd address the issue of [choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) before wondering why the results aren't as expected. I'd expect, as mentioned the problem is with leading/trailing spaces/tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments it's likely due to leading spaces in the values. If you do the following to remove any spaces from the values it should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM  xyz
WHERE REPLACE(DataDate, ' ', '')='20140609'
```

Alternately, you could use [**LTRIM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177827.aspx) / [**RTRIM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) functions to do this.

### [Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b394b/7)

```
create table SampleData(myDate varchar(50))

insert into SampleData(myDate) values(' 20140609 ')
insert into SampleData(myDate) values('20140608')
insert into SampleData(myDate) values('20140607')
insert into SampleData(myDate) values('20140606')
```

Both of these queries work in the fiddle:

```
SELECT *
FROM  SampleData
WHERE REPLACE(myDate, ' ', '')='20140609'

Select MAX(REPLACE(myDate, ' ', '')) from SampleData
```

### Future Advice:

Even so, it's not a good idea to save dates as varchar for numerous reasons so I would suggest changing that if possible.

The below would perform a conversion on your existing data to convert them to valid dates, whilst removing any spaces, assuming your dates are always in the format `YYYYMMDD`:

```
SELECT cast(REPLACE(DataDate, ' ', '') as DateTime) FormattedDate
FROM  xyz
```

To implement this, you could create a new `DateTime` column on the table and insert the correct date values in to there with something like below and then modify your code to use the new column:

First add a new column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz 
ADD FormattedDate DateTime NULL
```

Then update the data in the new column so it holds the converted dates:

```
UPDATE xyz
SET FormattedDate = cast(REPLACE(DataDate, ' ', '') as DateTime)
```

Comment: Awesome man... Thanks... ill try it out. 
And I cant change to DateTime because I am not the provider of data nor the User. So sorry for that.

Comment: @JayNirgudkar no problem, I was aware you may not be able to change the data, but it was intended to possibly help you but also for anyone else that views the question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

in sql spaces count as the character. Then use like operator to this query as

SELECT
 *
FROM
 xyz
WHERE
 DataDate  like '%20140609%'

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the query as below and give it a go ?

```
 SELECT
 *
FROM
 xyz
WHERE
 DataDate ='2014-06-09'
```

Comment: Nothing. It works for the other dates(similar type) that I have. It just doesnt work for this entry. And the DataDate Column is also in varchar and not in Date

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to make the date columns in varchar format, else can you try alter the table? The max function will only apply to the string and will not give the maximum value of date